# Чем заменить background-clip: text в IE 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Известно, что background-clip не поддерживается в IE 11, однако текст необходимо сделать градиентным. Кроме того, существует полифилл для IE 11

```
 /**
  -webkit-background-clip: text Polyfill

  # What? #
  A polyfill which replaces the specified element with a SVG
  in browser where "-webkit-background-clip: text" 
  is not available.

  Fork it on GitHub
  https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill

  # 2013 by Tim Pietrusky
  # timpietrusky.com
**/

Element.prototype.backgroundClipPolyfill = function () {
  var a = arguments[0],
      d = document,
      b = d.body,
      el = this;

  function hasBackgroundClip() {
    return b.style.webkitBackgroundClip != undefined;
  };

  function addAttributes(el, attributes) {
    for (var key in attributes) {
      el.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
    }
  }

  function createSvgElement(tagname) {
    return d.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagname);
  }

  function createSVG() {
    var a = arguments[0],
        svg = createSvgElement('svg'),
        pattern = createSvgElement('pattern'),
        image = createSvgElement('image'),
        text = createSvgElement('text');

    // Add attributes to elements
    addAttributes(pattern, {
      'id' : a.id,
      'patternUnits' : 'userSpaceOnUse',
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });

    addAttributes(image, {
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });
    image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', a.url);

    addAttributes(text, {
      'x' : 0,
      'y' : 80,
      'class' : a['class'],
      'style' : 'fill:url(#' + a.id + ');'
    });

    // Set text
    text.textContent = a.text;

    // Add elements to pattern
    pattern.appendChild(image);

    // Add elements to SVG
    svg.appendChild(pattern);
    svg.appendChild(text);

    return svg;
  };

  /*
   * Replace the element if background-clip
   * is not available.
   */
  if (!hasBackgroundClip()) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var svg = createSVG({
        'id' : a.patternID,
        'url' : a.patternURL,
        'class' : a['class'],
        'width' : this.width,
        'height' : this.height,
        'text' : el.textContent
      });

      el.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, el);
    }
    img.src = a.patternURL;
  }
};

var element = document.querySelector('.headline'); 

/*
 * Call the polyfill
 *
 * patternID : the unique ID of the SVG pattern
 * patternURL : the URL to the background-image
 * class : the css-class applied to the SVG
 */
element.backgroundClipPolyfill({
  'patternID' : 'mypattern',
  'patternURL' : 'http://timpietrusky.com/cdn/army.png',
  'class' : 'headline'
});
```

однако он работает с картинками, а не линейными градиентами (поскольку при вызове backgroundClipPolyfill необходимо указывать URL, что при linear-gradient вместо картинки не представляется возможным). Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Эх.. Жаль нельзя заменить IE..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если просто использовать SVG то есть вообще использовать SVG вместо background-clip ?

Тогда мы получим абсолютно кроссбраузерный метод

> Если мой ответ не является получением нужной информации то поясните что требуется

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -20 242 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient"  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop stop-color="red"  offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <text x="0" y="0" fill="url(#linearGradient)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="22px">
   This is preview svg text
  </text>
 </g>
</svg>
```